# How can I filter and select only PNG images with Jetpack Compose Photo Picker?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, imagepicker

I'm using Jetpack Compose and the Photo Picker to allow users to select images in my app. However, I want to restrict the selection to only PNG images. How can I implement this filter when using the Photo Picker in Jetpack Compose?

Here's the code I have for opening the Photo Picker using the button onClick:

```
val multiplePhotoPickerLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.PickMultipleVisualMedia(),
    onResult = { uris -> })

// Below code for open image picker
Button(modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .bounceClick(),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    White, disabledContainerColor = White80,
                    disabledContentColor = White
                ),
                onClick = {
                    multiplePhotoPickerLauncher.launch(PickVisualMediaRequest(ActivityResultContracts.PickVisualMedia.ImageOnly)
                    )
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    color = Black80,
                    text = "${attachments.size} / 10"
                )
            }
```

Comment: You can set mime type to image/png.

Comment: https://medium.com/@everydayprogrammer/implement-android-photo-picker-in-android-studio-3562a85c85f1

Answer (score 0):

You should set the [MIME type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#MIME_header_fields) like this:

```
val mimeType = "image/png"


onClick = {
            multiplePhotoPickerLauncher.launch(
                PickVisualMediaRequest(
                    ActivityResultContracts
                        .PickVisualMedia.SingleMimeType(mimeType))
            )
        }
```